# Is kafka container factory a requirement in Spring Kafka?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a simple consumer in Spring working. I have a config class defined with a bunch of factories, etc. When I remove the config class, the consumer still works. I'm wondering the benefit of having the factory, ie:

```java
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,
            GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }

    public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(retrieveConsumerConfigs());
    }
```

and now just passing vals in via application properties and calling it a day. I have explicit control over the config in the class-based approach, but was also thinking I could drop the class and have the vals be available through the spring env variables like spring.kafka.bootstrapservers, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container factory is required for `@KafkaListener` methods.

Spring Boot will auto-configure one (from application.properties/yml) if you don't provide your own bean. See `KafkaAutoConfiguration`.

Boot will also configure the consumer factory (if you don't).

An application, typically, does not need to declare any infrastructure beans.

**EDIT**

I prefer to never declare my own infrastructure beans. If I need some feature that is not exposed as a Boot property, or where I want to override some property for just one container, I simply add a customizer bean.

```java
@Component
class Customizer {

    public Customizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {

        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            if (container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId().equals("slowGroup")) {
                container.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(60_000);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

or

```java
@Component
class Customizer {

    Customizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> containerFactory,
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec) {

        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(exec);
    }

}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I got everything working, it's pretty nice removing my class and delegating via properties. Thoughts on that? Maybe if I need a ton more control a class makes sense, but I'm not doing much outside manual acks, etc.

Comment: `>Thoughts on that? Maybe if I need a ton more control a class makes sense,` See the edit to my answer.

Comment: hello, when we go through the spring-kafka tutorials on the internet, almost everyone is defining his own listener container factory bean, personally i don't think this is a good way to customise the factory bean (because spring does it for us based on applicaiton.yml where we can centralize the kafka configs), the way you mention via a Customizer seems to be the correct way, but i am wondring  how we can ensure that the customization (the code in Customizer constructor) is done before the listener the container factory being used ?thank you

Comment: If you are only using the factory for `@KafkaListener`s, it is guaranteed that no container will be created until all beans have been instantiated. The KLABPP is a `SmartInitializingSingleton` and it causes the containers to be created in `afterSingletonsInstantiated()`. If you are using the factory to create containers in your own code, you may need some similar logic. In future, ask such questions in a new question; questions in comments don't help others to find answers to questions.

Comment: thank you Gary, i will create new question next time.

Answer (score 2):

the simple consumer in Spring works because spring-boot auto-configuration under the hoods creates an object of `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and registers it with the spring container.

You can validate it by injecting the implementation of `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` as done below:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    private final KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory) {
        System.out.println(kafkaListenerContainerFactory instanceof ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory);
        this.kafkaListenerContainerFactory = kafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }
}
```

But if you are not happy with spring boot's auto-generated bean, you can create your own bean and register it with the spring container by using `@Bean` annotation